# Java Thread Sleep exactly specific amount of time (including some process)

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, sleep, vlcj

I am trying to develop a simulation and the main thread should wait exactly 40ms in each iteration, because simulation is run with 25fps. In this 40ms, some process time is included. This means, remaining_time = 40ms - some_process_time. So I think, I need to use, for example:

```
while (true)
  {
    long processStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    //some process is going on here...
    remaining_time = 40 - (System.currentTimeMillis() - processStartTime)
    Thread.sleep(remaining_time);
  }
```

In each iteration, remaining_time changes (some times 1ms, sometimes 2ms) based on the process time. I want to synchronize the simulation with a video, using VLCJ. But after some time, synchronization between the simulation and video cannot be achieved. What is the best way to sync a video with a simulation code?

Comment: When you say "must wait 40ms", do you mean "must be notified every frame, assuming 25 fps"? The best way to sync, if VLCJ provides this facility, would be for VLCJ to notify your code when a new frame is played (or every X frames/when particular timecode are reached during playback...). Have you checked if VLCJ has such a callback facility?

Comment: If you're using sleep, then I doubt you'll be able to rely on sleeping to 40ms each time and assuming it will keep in sync reliably. I imagine you'll have to (periodically at least) query the current playback position and then adjust the sleep time so that the point in your simulation matches. Bear in mind too that System.nanoTime() is likely to give more accurate timings, and that Thread.sleep() can be arbitrarily woken early or sleep longer than requested. Also, be wary of Thread.sleep(0) being interpreted as 'sleep for infinite time': avoid this case if you're calculating the value.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't get VLCJ to provide callbacks, then I would suggest trying to adopt the following strategy:

- On each loop, query the video player for its current playback position (I assume you can do this). Call this 't0'.
- Calculate how many frames' worth of simulation you should have run by that point, and run as many as you need to catch up (on average, you hope this will be 1)
- Time the calculation of those simulation frames (using System.nanoTime(), as it will typically be more accurate). (Note that you're still only interested in the time to the nearest millisecond, just that taking the measurements from System.nanoTime() and then dividing by 1000000 will typically be more accurate than using System.currentTimeMillis(). You can *request* a sleep in nanoseconds, but I've not found a system that actually honours this.)
- Now, calculate how many mills you need to sleep to reach t1, which is t0 + the time for one frame; sleep for that number of mills if greater than 0

So you sleep towards a target playback point, rather assuming that (process + sleep) must equal 40ms for each frame.

The problem with your scheme is the cumulative errors in the sleep time. Remember that the OS does not guarantee that it will sleep for exactly the number of millis requested, and in any case, timings in milliseconds are only accurate to a couple of per cent when you're timing something in the order of 40ms!

Now that said, in practice, you might not want to query the playback position literally on every single loop (I imagine there's a performance overhead if the VLCJ library is based on native methods), and you might find that just sleeping (40-processing time) milliseconds on each frame *is* accurate enough for, say, ten frames at a time.

Comment: I can get VLCJ callbacks. There's a performance overhead if callbacks are used. I need to think about the other solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can improve precision with this change

```
        long startTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
        long count=0;
        while (true)
          {
            long processStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            //some process is going on here...
            count++;
            long remaining_time =  startTime+count*40 - processStartTime;
            if (remaining_time>0L)
                Thread.sleep(remaining_time);
          }
```